# An error occurred in submitting my question, but I don't know why

Tags: bug, status-norepro, stack-overflow, questions, error-message

I've tried submitting the following question a couple of times, and each time I get the message: **An error occurred submitting the question**. I don't know what the problem is. Why am I getting this error?

The question I'm attempting to post is this:

> I have been asked to add Spring Security in a project. Previously,
>   hashing was done manually like this:
>
> ```
> public final class PasswordEncryption
> {
>   private static PasswordEncryption instance;
>   private PasswordEncryption() 
>   {
>   }
>   public synchronized String encrypt(String plaintext) throws UnavailableException
>   {
>     MessageDigest md = null;
>     try
>     {
>       md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256"); //step 2
>     }
>     catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
>     {
>       System.out.println("NoSuchAlgorithmException");
>
>     }
>     try
>     {
>       md.update(plaintext.getBytes("UTF-8")); //step 3
>     }
>     catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e)
>     {
>       throw new UnavailableException(e.getMessage());
>     }
>     byte raw[] = md.digest(); //step 4
>     String hash = (new BASE64Encoder()).encode(raw); //step 5
>     return hash; //step 6
>   }
>   public static synchronized PasswordEncryption getInstance() //step 1
>   {
>     if(instance == null)
>     {
>       return new PasswordEncryption();
>     }
>     else    
>     {
>       return instance;
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> Now I have changed it to this:
>
> ```
> <authentication-manager>      <authentication-provider>           <password-encoder hash="sha-256" base64="true" />
>       <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
>           users-by-username-query="
>         select username, password, status 
>         from user where email = ?" />         </authentication-provider>  </authentication-manager>
> ```
>
> When i try to login, I get the error `Bad credentials`. I have checked
>   the query it is correct and returns the correct value. So I figure the
>   problem must be in hashing.

[image: Error]

Comment: Did you try again?

Comment: I'm guessing it's because the *entire* post is within a blockquote.

Comment: @Jamal I did that just for this question. My original question has no blockquotes.

Comment: Why is this question being voted to be closed as a programming question? ***This is an on-topic meta question***, people! It just has a programming question _quoted in it_, because it is _about_ that programming question.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot? Maybe there is a message you simply are seeing but not noticing?

Comment: When I was adding this screenshot, I got another error: `Error in posting edit`. So I had to upload it from my colleague's PC. But when I tried posting my original question from his computer it still showed the same error.

Comment: What title have you used for the question? And what IP address are you posting from when showing this error?

Comment: @Oded The title is 'Spring Security hash not working properly' and I am using my company proxy server whose IP is 223.30.78.110.

Comment: OK. Wanted to rule out a few options. Are you still unable to post the question? Can you log out, clear all your cookies, log back in and try again if so?

Comment: @Oded That did it. Thanks.

Comment: @Oded think this better be posted as answer so it can be used as reference.

Comment: FWIW, I frequently get this error when answering questions, and it's because my internet has dropped.